# Expo, React Native, Share/upload picture to Facebook (story on my own page)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, react-native, expo, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-image

I am really lost here, I have an Expo React-Native application. the user can login with Facebook credentials.

```
  loginWithFacebook = async () => {
    const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FACBOOK_APP_ID, {
      permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
    });

    if (type === 'success') {
      this.callGraph(token);
    } else {...});
    }
  };
```

and

```
callGraph = async (token) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,email,picture`);
    const responceJSON = JSON.stringify(await response.json());
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['FBResponse', responceJSON], ['FBToken', token]]);
    } catch (error) {...}
  };
```

now I have the Token and info of the loged in user. now I get a picture from cameraRoll

```
  pickImage = async () => {
    const result = await Expo.ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({...});
  };
```

which gives the URI of the image at the device, also I am using `RNFetchBlob` to again have the image as base64.
but I am really confused that how should I share/upload this picture to Facebook. Should I eject from Expo install FBSDK and do it from Android folder? or I can do it with the Graph API? or I can Link it to Expo?
I could not find a single example, just simple `react-native-share` samples are what I see everywhere.

Comment: You can do it with Graph API. Chek [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook integration for Expo only accepts read permissions and one cannot login with `publish_actions` it seems the community is still [working on it](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/loginwithpublishpermissions-for-facebook-api). and for using `fbsdk` you should either eject from Expo or ask for permissions via the Expo [WebBrowser](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser.html#expowebbrowseropenauthsessionasyncurl-redirecturl) integration.